# Openerp Unable to Show more then 100 Meetings in Calendar View?

Tags: python, odoo

When I create meetings in openerp for any user.. I can see them on both Calendar View and List View.. How ever When My meetings exceeds 100 for a single user it doesn't show newly created meetings in calendar view. How ever I can see all of them in my list view... Have any one faced this problem before.. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented with the calendar view for the CRM cases screen. (I don't have the meetings module installed.) It looks like the calender view doesn't update itself right away, and you can force it by moving to the next month and then back.

Here's what I did, maybe you can do something similar:

1. Open the list view. Open the last item in the list and check what date it's on.
2. Switch to the calendar view and make sure that item is visible on that date.
3. Switch back to the list view, expand the search filters at the top and reduce the limit from 200 to 20.
4. Click the find button to get a much shorter list.
5. Switch to the calendar view. At this point, I expect that the item I looked at before will be gone, but it's still visible.
6. Move to the next month, and then back. Now the item is gone.

I did all this in OpenERP 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,even I encountered the same problem.This is actually a limitation in OpenERP.So I created a new class called Meeting_history.So when meetings exceeds more than 90,the first 10 meetings or the  older ten meetings gets removed from crm_meeting table and gets stored in meeting_history class where we can view older meetings of that user.